# How to check if an instance is of type String or GString in Groovy

Tags: groovy, types

I would like to learn what the robust way of checking, if a variable is of type string or gstring, is. I suppose it is different than in pure Java:

```
def var = someFunc();

if (var instanceof String || var instanceof GString) {
   String str = var;
}
```

I ask, because I do not want to be surprised that I have missed a Groovy specific feature that causes a hard to debug bug.

Comment: Disappointing there's not a neater way to do this, e.g. var.isString()

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Instanceof tests should work:

```
assert "fasd" instanceof String
assert "${this}" instanceof GString
```

Answer (score 19):

Another way is to use the `in` keyword:

```
groovy:000> t = "hello"
===> hello
groovy:000> t in String
===> true
groovy:000> "${t}" in GString
===> true
```

The `in` keyword is the membership operator, and gets translated to an `isCase` call on the class:

```
groovy:000> String.isCase(t)
===> true
groovy:000> GString.isCase("${t}")
===> true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `.class` method on a Groovy object

```
def a = "test"
def b = "${a}"

assert a.class == String
assert b.class == org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
```

Note that a `GString` is easily evaluated and turned into a `String`, e.g. by calls to `toString`.

If you're looking for template-like functionality to have re-usable string definitions to pass around and leverage, you should consider the `Groovy` template engine.

see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates

Comment: You have to be careful is `a` is a `Map` though, as `a.class` will return `null`