# What is the difference between the 'instanceof' and 'in' keywords?

Tags: groovy, types, instanceof

**For the purposes of verifying class membership**, the `in` and `instanceof` keywords appear to behave identically.  So what's the difference between the two?  Is there even a difference at all?  There are several questions on StackOverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378718/how-to-check-if-an-instance-is-of-type-string-or-gstring-in-groovy) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060427/groovy-grails-how-to-determine-a-data-type)) where both keywords are given as solutions for this purpose, but there is no mention on the difference between the two or when it is more appropriate to use one over the other.  Additionally, the official documention mentions that [the `in` keyword is equivalent to calling an object's `isCase()` method](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_membership_operator), but doesn't detail what the `instanceof` keyword does.

---

Both keywords appear to behave identically with respect to class inheritance and interface implementation:

```
class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap { }

def foo = new LinkedHashMap()
def bar = new MyMap()

println("LinkedHashMap instance is 'in' LinkedHashMap: ${foo in LinkedHashMap}")
println("LinkedHashMap instance is 'instanceof' LinkedHashMap: ${foo instanceof LinkedHashMap}")
println("LinkedHashMap instance is 'in' Map: ${foo in Map}")
println("LinkedHashMap instance is 'instanceof' Map: ${foo instanceof Map}")
println("MyMap instance is 'in' LinkedHashMap: ${bar in LinkedHashMap}")
println("MyMap instance is 'instanceof' LinkedHashMap: ${bar instanceof LinkedHashMap}")
println("MyMap instance is 'in' Map: ${bar in Map}")
println("MyMap instance is 'instanceof' Map: ${bar instanceof Map}")
```

Output:

```
LinkedHashMap instance is 'in' LinkedHashMap: true
LinkedHashMap instance is 'instanceof' LinkedHashMap: true
LinkedHashMap instance is 'in' Map: true
LinkedHashMap instance is 'instanceof' Map: true
MyMap instance is 'in' LinkedHashMap: true
MyMap instance is 'instanceof' LinkedHashMap: true
MyMap instance is 'in' Map: true
MyMap instance is 'instanceof' Map: true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is that `instanceof` is a Java keyword, while `obj in SomeClass` is an equivalent of `SomeClass.isCase(obj)` method call as you mentioned in your question.

There is one major implication: `instanceof` cannot be overridden and as Oracle docs says:

> *The `instanceof` operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.*
>
> ---
>
> *Source: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html_)*

`Class.isCase(obj)` is implemented as follows:

```
/**
 * Special 'Case' implementation for Class, which allows testing
 * for a certain class in a switch statement.
 * For example:
 * <pre>switch( obj ) {
 *   case List :
 *     // obj is a list
 *     break;
 *   case Set :
 *     // etc
 * }</pre>
 *
 * @param caseValue   the case value
 * @param switchValue the switch value
 * @return true if the switchValue is deemed to be assignable from the given class
 * @since 1.0
 */
public static boolean isCase(Class caseValue, Object switchValue) {
    if (switchValue instanceof Class) {
        Class val = (Class) switchValue;
        return caseValue.isAssignableFrom(val);
    }
    return caseValue.isInstance(switchValue);
}
```

*Source: [org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L1121](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_5_X/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L1121)*

As you can see based on the source code Groovy's `obj in SomeClass` is not an alias to `instanceof`, because it does a bit more. However, there is one important thing worth mentioning - you can override `isCase()` implementation, but you can't change how `instanceof` Java keyword behaves. Overriding `Class.isCase()` may cause some damage to your code if you use it as an alternative to Java's `instanceof` keyword.

Comment: Wow, very thorough answer with sources.  Thanks!  I'm also curious if there are any cases where `someObject instanceof SomeClass` would have different behavior than `someObject in SomeClass` (barring overriding `isCase()`).  Based on the information given, it would seem that, for all practical purposes, the two behave the same, even if they are not strictly equivalent.

Comment: Found one difference: `Object in Class` -> false.  `Object instanceof Class` -> true.